# XML parsing nested JSON using retrofit

Tags: android, xml, retrofit2

```
<Res><Payload>{"Queues":{"Queue":[{"Name":"someproject"}]}}</Payload></Res>
```

How can I read the JSON object within the XML element tags by using Retrofit?

this is my POJO class for XML parsing

```
@Root(name = "Res", strict = false) 
public class PingResponse { 
    @Root(name = "Payload", strict = false) 
    public PingPayLoad pingPayLoad; 
} 

@Root(name = "Payload", strict = false) 
class PingPayLoad { 
    @Element(name = "Queues") 
    public Queues queues; 

    public Queues getQueues() { return queues; } 
    public void setQueues(Queues queues) { this.queues = queues; } 

    @Element(name = "Queues") 
    class Queues { } 
}
```

Comment: Define your Java POJO to extract a string. Parse the content later. How far in that process are you? Please [edit] to include code

Comment: Please i can t understand can u ellobrate u r explanation

Comment: @Root(name = "Response", strict = false)
public class PingResponse {


    @Root(name = "Payload", strict = false)
    public PingPayLoad pingPayLoad;

  




}
@Root(name = "Payload", strict = false)
 class PingPayLoad {


    @Element(name = "Queues")
    public Queues queues;



    public Queues getQueues() {
        return queues;
    }

    public void setQueues(Queues queues) {
        this.queues = queues;
    }
}

@Element(name = "Queues")
 class Queues {

} this is the correct way to parse

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Retrofit converter code only can read XML data, therefore, you have no queues to get parsed

Make the Payload a string field.

```
@Root(name = "Res", strict = false) 
public class PingResponse { 
    @Element(name = "Payload", strict = false) 
    public String  Payload; 
}
```

Define methods elsewhere to create and parse a JSONObject instance